get an item of the output after applying str.split to a polars dataframe column
how can i select last item of list in paths column after applying the str.split("/") function?
dataNpaths = pl.scan_csv("test_data/file*.csv", has_header=True, include_file_paths = "paths").collect()
dataNpaths.with_columns(pl.col("paths").str.split("/").alias("paths"))

>>> dataNpaths.with_columns(pl.col("paths").str.split("/").alias("paths"))
shape: (30, 5)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬────────────────────────────┐
│ Column1  ┆ Column2  ┆ Column3  ┆ Column4  ┆ paths                      │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---                        │
│ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ list[str]                  │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪════════════════════════════╡
│ 0.603847 ┆ 0.509877 ┆ 0.091579 ┆ 0.43821  ┆ ["test_data", "file1.csv"] │
│ 0.572299 ┆ 0.817647 ┆ 0.087951 ┆ 0.397217 ┆ ["test_data", "file1.csv"] │
│ 0.886123 ┆ 0.159805 ┆ 0.766246 ┆ 0.083915 ┆ ["test_data", "file1.csv"] │
│ 0.142208 ┆ 0.413847 ┆ 0.043408 ┆ 0.147779 ┆ ["test_data", "file1.csv"] │
│ 0.105215 ┆ 0.924754 ┆ 0.309823 ┆ 0.724407 ┆ ["test_data", "file1.csv"] │
│ …        ┆ …        ┆ …        ┆ …        ┆ …                          │
│ 0.381675 ┆ 0.849887 ┆ 0.498281 ┆ 0.733085 ┆ ["test_data", "file3.csv"] │
│ 0.697427 ┆ 0.950464 ┆ 0.999596 ┆ 0.645253 ┆ ["test_data", "file3.csv"] │
│ 0.49979  ┆ 0.172414 ┆ 0.679287 ┆ 0.091804 ┆ ["test_data", "file3.csv"] │
│ 0.668585 ┆ 0.640259 ┆ 0.932463 ┆ 0.579558 ┆ ["test_data", "file3.csv"] │
│ 0.077462 ┆ 0.802565 ┆ 0.966791 ┆ 0.29297  ┆ ["test_data", "file3.csv"] │

but neither of these approaches worked
dataNpaths.with_columns(pl.col("paths").str.split("/")[-1].alias("paths"))
dataNpaths.with_columns(pl.col("paths").str.split("/",-1).alias("paths"))


You should the List accessor .list which is similar to .str:
dataNpaths.with_columns(pl.col("paths").str.split("/").list[-1])

.alias('paths') is superfluous as you are using the old column name not creating a new column.
Alternatively as the last element of the List is needed, the same result can be obtained using a .list method:
dataNpaths.with_columns(pl.col("paths").str.split("/").list.last())

Details of the comprehensive .list methods are given in LINK. These include .slice, .contains, .head, .tail etc.
